# Image upload resulting in error message PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, ftp

I have created PHP so far to upload images directly onto the page for any public viewing. The problem I am getting is that once i have selected the image i want to upload, then clicked on the submit button. it goes onto another page and shows error message saying `Parse error.`

Also can this function be used without an FTP server as I do want the public to be able to view it.

I have included a jSFiddle with the relevant HTML, PHP and also the CSS.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/PYgtp/

Comment: With all respect, we will not sit through and decipher your code & do your troubleshooting for you.. it's best you sit through your code, getting your parameters, and performing typical troubleshooting steps.. Then report to SO if you still can't figure out your problem

Comment: @Viccari   Hi what did you edit in this post? Thanks

Comment: @DarylGill Hi Daryl. I have been troubleshooting for the past 4 days and have got no where. that is the reason that I have posted the question. Thanks

Comment: He has removed the `many thanks` from your question. Furthermore, can you post what you have tried? what section of the code have you minimized the problem to? A more exact error message apart from `parse error`.. Does it work with uploading all files? or certain file types?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line of code:

```
header("Refresh: $seconds; URL="$location"");
```

to

```
header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
```

Comment: Hi. i have made this change and still have no luck. any further help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: What happened afterwards?  When I ran the code and made that change, I got some crappy-looking page, but it stopped giving the error.